# Объект типа String[] заполнить в виде объекта JSON массива

Tags: java, json, android-studio, строки

Здравствуйте! Можно ли `String [] myJson` заполнить

```
{
"status": "active",
"error": "No error",
"type": "sms",
"data": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Кукуруза на Марсе",
    "params": {
        "1": "Возможно",
        "2": "Невозможно",
        "3": "Бред",
        "4": "А где это?",
        "6": "А что это?"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя. Многомерных массивов в Java нет, только через велосипед.

Comment: Мне нужно отправить эти данные на сервер, используя авторизации в заголовке Authorization. Посоветуйте пожалуйста как это сделать. Если будет пример с исходнимаки был бы безмерно благодарен))

Comment: @АлишерИсмоилов покажите код, потому что я не знаю сервера, которому бы при HTTP-авторизации нужно было юы такое отправлять. В идеале - гляньте сниффером что отправляет браузер и в каком виде, быть может достаточно обычной строкой ему отправить.

Comment: нужно отправить выше приведенный пример json, единственное условие с использованием авторизации в заголовке

Comment: @diraria я и говорю. Велосипед

Comment: Пример велосипеда в исходниках можно посмотреть?

Comment: @АлишерИсмоилов создайте json object, зачем Вам string[]?

Comment: Потому что я использовал пример https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUXWezYL5BY. Если нужно могу предоставить исходный код

Comment: вы, наверное, хотели сказать "ассоциативных массивов в Java нет"

Comment: @etki А как же Map? Речь ведь шла про String.

Comment: Кто нибудь, помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

Comment: @АлишерИсмоилов добавьте код. И вообще, на Ваш вопрос ответ дан. Это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Все пишут, что это "велосипед", но никто не смог показать как он ездит! Это мой второй вопрос, как отправить на сервер данные методом POST используя заголовок авторизации... печально, что никто не может помочь((

Comment: @АлишерИсмоилов Нельзя давать ответ на вопрос, не связанный с основным вопросом, это собьет с толку человека, который найдет вопрос. Создайте новый.

Comment: @Hombre это немного абстрактней того, что обычно подразумевают под ассоциативным массивом. Но я акцентировал то, что многомерные массивы в java вполне себе есть.